# docker-compose up `require': cannot load such file -- pg (LoadError)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, entry-point

I got this error bin/entrypoint:6:in `require': cannot load such file -- pg (LoadError) when I run docker-compose up, can anyone help? Thanks

bin/entrypoint

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'timeout'
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'pg'
...
```

dockerfile

```
ARG SERVER_ROOT=/srv/app
ARG RUBY_VERSION=2.6.6
ARG NODE_VERSION=12.18
ARG YARN_VERSION=1.22.4

FROM ruby:${RUBY_VERSION}-alpine AS gem
ARG SERVER_ROOT

RUN apk add --no-cache postgresql-dev build-base ca-certificates zlib-dev libressl-dev git

RUN mkdir -p ${SERVER_ROOT}
ADD Gemfile Gemfile.lock ${SERVER_ROOT}/

WORKDIR ${SERVER_ROOT}
RUN gem install bundler:2.1.4 \
...
```

docker-compose

```
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.2
    command:
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:9000"
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
    depends_on:
      - etm
  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: XXX
      POSTGRES_USER: XXX
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: XXX
      ...
```

Comment: How are you building and running the image that contains that script; or is that outside Docker in your development setup?  Do you have a `Gemfile` that includes the required gems?  Are you running `bundler install` at some point?

Comment: here is my dockerfile, and I'm sure the gem is in the gemfile and is installed.

`ARG SERVER_ROOT=/srv/app
ARG RUBY_VERSION=2.6.6
ARG NODE_VERSION=12.18
ARG YARN_VERSION=1.22.4

FROM ruby:${RUBY_VERSION}-alpine AS gem
ARG SERVER_ROOT

RUN apk add --no-cache postgresql-dev build-base ca-certificates zlib-dev libressl-dev git

RUN mkdir -p ${SERVER_ROOT}
ADD Gemfile Gemfile.lock ${SERVER_ROOT}/

ARG XXX
WORKDIR ${SERVER_ROOT}`

Comment: `$ docker-compose up
Creating network "ptboxes_default" with the default driver
Creating ptboxes_redis_1    ... done
Creating ptboxes_postgres_1 ... done
Creating ptboxes_sidekiq_1  ... done
Creating ptboxes_etm_1      ... done
Creating ptboxes_traefik_1  ... done
Attaching to ptboxes_redis_1, ptboxes_postgres_1, ptboxes_etm_1, ptboxes_sidekiq_1, ptboxes_traefik_1
etm_1       | bin/entrypoint:6:in 'require': cannot load such file -- pg (LoadError)
etm_1       |   from bin/entrypoint:6:in '<main>'`

Comment: Please edit the question to include these details.  Try to reduce it to a [mcve]: if, say, the Redis container isn't needed to demonstrate the issue, omit it.

Comment: I think I found the problem, the gemfile.lock is different from the bundler version of docker-compse, thanks for your help.